# Passing NSString from View Controller to TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

Can someone please advise on how to pass an array of NSStrings from a ViewController into a TableViewController. I have tried using prepareForSegue in my rootViewController

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
TableViewController *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

NSLog(@"Segue %@", segue.identifier);

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueAffiliation"])
{
    // segue Affiliation happened
    transferViewController.titleText = @"Friendly";

}
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueCategory"])
{
    // segue Category happened
}
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueFunction1"])
{
    // segue Function1 happened
}
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueFunction2"])
{
    // segue Function2 happened
}
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueFunction3"])
{
    // segue Function3 happened
}
```

and I am not sure on how to pass the data, so far I have this in the TableViewController

```
@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController
{
NSArray *_tableData;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Initialize table data

self.cellTitle.text = self.titleText;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [_tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath    *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Set Property of  your `NSArray *_tableData` .\

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail @Virussmca

Comment: there are lots of questions and answer related to it, please do little  search before posting it to SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to declare your array _tableData in your header file :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *_tableData;
```

And in your .m file :

```
@synthesize _tableData;
```

Currently _tableData is private.

Comment: Hi, @Shawn i tried doing that and the tableview is still not showing my string I'm trying to pass from the view controller

Comment: have you set your array in your viewcontroller ? transferViewController._tableData = yourArrayOfString;

Comment: Yep this is what I have done now    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueAffiliation"])
    {
        // segue Affiliation happened
        transferViewController._tableData = @[@"Joe Blogs"];
        
    }
@Shawn

Comment: Ok, I guess you have a UILabel or something similar in your cell, do you set it correctly at this point ? // Configure the cell... You must have something like cell.textLabel.text = [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

Comment: Figured it out, wasn't configuring the cell correctly. Thank you though @Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Create the property on next `view controller .h` and define getter and setter.

Add this `property` in NextVC.h on nextVC

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray * _tableData;
```

Add

`@synthesize  _tableData;`           in NextVC.m

And last

TableViewController *transferViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

```
    transferViewController._tableData=// your array.
```